# prevent normal user go into admin pages

Tags: php, laravel

In model, **User.php** I set a function call **isStatus()**

```
 public function isStatus(){
    return $this->status; // 1 of mysql table column name status, let say 0 is admin and 1 is normal user.

}
```

In controller name **LoginController.php**, I want to make it if user status is **0 will go /admin page**, **other will go to / page** which mean main page.

```
    protected function authenticated($request, $user){

    if($user->isStatus('0')){
        return redirect('/admin');
    }else{
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**User table with 'status' column are boolean** but is not working.

Comment: `if($user->isStatus('0')){` should be `if($user->isStatus() == '0'){`

Comment: Is your normal user able to login?

Comment: yeah is work....but how to prevent normal user to go in ? let say the status is 1, normal user are not able to go /admin pages but is still can go thru!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel, lets refactor a little bit of your code.

You are passing a parameter to your function  public function isStatus() with receives any parameter and returns a public value. Delete this function.

auth()->user() will get the connected user for you and you can access the status property just like this

> auth()->user()->status

Your function shoud look like this:

```
return auth()->user()->status ? redirect('/admin'): redirect('/');
```

You can put this validation in all your controllers that needs the role authentication.

If you are interested you can also check some modules out of the box developed by external vendors that treats real profesional the validations and avoid repetitive code.

Check them out

- https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
- https://github.com/Toddish/Verify-L4
- https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#laravel-4

and @Kuebel's favourite

- https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust

Comment: Please add my all time favorite: Laracast https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust ;)

Comment: Alright. I tried to add the code but is still able to pass it when I log in as normal user and still able to go thru on admin pages.

Comment: Did you set that logic at the Route Controllers? Also please confirm if auth()->user()->status is returning true or false

Comment: I tried to add it under Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@getLogout');}); but is still can go thru the admin page as the normal user.

Comment: Please try to add return Auth::user()->status ? redirect('/admin'): redirect('/'); at your app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php at the handle method and check if that works. Also avoid to write codes at your routes/web file. Only uses to set routers

Answer (score 0):

Your function `isStatus()` returns the status value of the user model.

In the controller you are calling the function with a parameter, however the function doesn't accept a parameter. This would be the correct controller code

```
if($user->isStatus()){         //Call the function without a parameter. Since this returns boolean (0 or 1) you don't need to add == 0)
    return redirect('/admin');
}else{
    return redirect('/');
}
```

And BTW: This kind of if has a short hand writing style:

```
($user->isStatus()) ? return redirect('/admin') : return redirect('/');
```

Read more about it [here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

Comment: Yeah. But the problem is as normal user i tried to add /admin , it still can go thru. What I want is it will directly go to main/index page.

Comment: Take a look at middleware. Basically, just check in your admin controller (on that method that displays /admin) if isStatus() is true, Else redirect back (or throw a 403 error)

Comment: This is not a problem. the problem is when isStatus() true or false, i tried to add '/admin' it still will go thru admin pages.